# Hive casting function

Tags: sql, hive, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

In a hive table how can I add the **'-'** sign in a field, but for random records? If I use the syntax below it changes **all** the records in the field to negative, but I want to change **random** records to negative.

This is the syntax I used which changed all the records to negative:

```sql
CAST(CAST(-1 AS DECIMAL(1,0)) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) 
*CAST(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(TRIM(column name),'\\-',''),'-','') as decimal(19,2)),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change random values to negative, why not use a `case` expression?

```
select (case when rand() < 0.5 then - column_name else column_name end)
```

Despite your query, this assumes that the column is a number of some sort, because negating strings doesn't make much sense.